# I wrote code that should give message's (I am blue) author a role, it doesn't work, rewrite my code please

Tags: python, discord.py

this is my code that should give message author a role:

## color roles

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    await bot.process_commands()
    user = ctx.message.author
    msg = message.content.lower
    role = discord.utils.get(discord.guild.roles, name = "blue as alian egg")
    if msg == ['I am blue']:
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

and this is my errors:

```
C:\Users\Егор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/Егор/PycharmProjects/Luiji/Luiji.py
Luiji is ready to work!
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Егор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Answer (score 1):

`on_message` does not have a ctx, it should just be

```
async def on_message(message):
```

That is what the error `on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` means, you have an extra argument, message.